# assigning DB cluster parameter groups to DB clusters via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services

[Working with DB cluster parameter groups for Multi-AZ DB clusters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithDBClusterParamGroups.html) talks about how to create DB parameter groups, modify parameters within a DB cluster parameter group, reset parameters, copy them, list them, view parameters within a parameter group, etc, but it *doesn't* talk about how to assign a DB cluster to a particular parameter group.

I can change it in the web interface by going to Amazon RDS -> Databases -> [db name] -> Modify -> "DB cluster parameter group" and then selecting the one I'd like from the drop down menu but I'd like to be able to change it via the CLI.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the AWS CLI docs for RDS.

Particularly: [`modify-db-cluster`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-cluster.html)

```
aws rds modify-db-cluster

Description

Modifies the settings of an Amazon Aurora DB cluster or a Multi-AZ DB cluster. 
You can change one or more settings by specifying these parameters
 and the new values in the request.

--db-cluster-parameter-group-name (string)

    The name of the DB cluster parameter group to use for the DB cluster.

    Valid for Cluster Type: Aurora DB clusters and Multi-AZ DB clusters
```